# Webix ajax with CORS working everywhere except IE

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, internet-explorer, webix

Yesterday morning the AJAX calls from a webix widget I created stopped working in IE (tested IE10 and 11). It was working with IE up until yesterday morning.

I've restored the php files I modified yesterday morning from a backup but still cannot make AJAX calls using IE. I've created a Webix snippet to help illustrate the problem I'm having (http://webix.com/snippet/2047ef57).

If you click the button in the snippet/example in anything except IE you get a list of knee surgeons from an orthopedic surgery clinic. If you try to run the same code in IE you get a "Script Error" message.

I've tried both GET and POST for making this request to avoid IE caching issues I read about online.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try to get my PHP working again in IE?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Yes, and tried the snippet/example from multiple workstations, all with the same result. I've reached out for help on the Webix support forums (http://forum.webix.com/discussion/4463/ie-cors-problems#latest) but since they're in Belarus I don't know when they'll get back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webix library is browser-sniffing, and using ActiveX instead of XMLHttpRequest for IE:

```js
getXHR: function () {
    return webix.env.isIE
        ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlHTTP")
        : new XMLHttpRequest;
}
```

If you switch the user-agent string of the browser, and thus break this browser-detection, you'll note that the cross-domain request goes through without issues.

You can confirm this by following the below steps:

1. Press F12 to open the Developer Tools
2. Switch to the Emulation tab (Ctrl+8)
3. Set User Agent String to "Google Chrome"

At this point the tab will refresh. Press your button, and note that the results are received as expected.

This test that webix is doing should first check for XMLHttpRequest support, and use it if it's present. The approach of testing the browser, rather than the feature, is not recommended (evident by your issue):

Try adding the following to override this logic with our own test:

```js
webix.ajax.prototype.getXHR = function () {
    return XMLHttpRequest
        ? new XMLHttpRequest
        : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlHTTP");
}
```

Test online: http://webix.com/snippet/5e654155

Comment: Last night I also got a response from Webix informing me of the ActiveX issue as well. They suggested setting the isIE flag to false, but I prefer your solution of modifying the prototype instead, as it seems like it would be more versatile and less likely to break anything else I may ever need to do that would be IE dependent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that you can do based on the Webix documentation for CORS scenario. Either you:

1. Configure the server where your PHP files are hosted so that it allows any client from another domain to get data from it

   http://docs.webix.com/desktop__crossdomain_loading.html

Or

2. Change your client-side code and use JSONP technique with webix.jsonp() method - code snippet can be found in the link I provided above

The first option is ideal if you have access the web server's configuration to respond with a specific "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header for http requests. But in case you don't have that much control then second item is your choice

Comment: I had already implemented option 1, which is why it was working for every other browser. Option 2 wasn't an option because I needed to POST in other parts of my webapp, and JSONP only works for GET.